# How do I align flexbox navigation bar to the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, header, navbar

I just have a quick question as I've run into a problem I am unable to solve. I just need a logo to be on the left of the container and navigation links (top-bar) on the left. Where is the problem in my code?

HTML:

```
<header>
        <div class="container">

            <?php
            $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod('custom_logo');
            $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom_logo_id, 'full');

            if (has_custom_logo()) {
                echo '<a href="http://website.test/" class="site-link pull-left"> <img class="site-logo" src="' . esc_url($logo[0]) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo('name') . '"> </a>';
            } else {
                echo '<h1 class="site-logo">' . get_bloginfo('name') . '</h1>';
            }
            ?>

            <?php
            wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
                    'menu_class' => 'top-bar'
                )
            );
            ?>
        </div>

    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header .container {
    height: 20%;
    z-index: 99;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

header .container .site-logo {
    align-items: flex-start;
}

header .container .top-bar {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: `logo { margin-right: auto; }` will leave the logo at the left and pushes everything else to the right. `margin: auto` works same as flex-grow by cinsuming all remaining space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it sadly did not work, no change at all.

Comment: woukd be helpfull if you would post a [repro] instead of unparsed php

Comment: You say in the title "How do I align flexbox navigation bar to the right?", then in the beginning of your post you say "I just need a logo to be on the left of the container and navigation links (top-bar) on the left" can you please clarify what you want? –

Comment: I apologoize for the poorly worded title, I need the logo on the left and navigation links are not logo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a logo image, it is wrapped in an `<a>` tag. So the margin needs to be applied to the `<a>`. When there is no logo image, the margin should be applied to the `<h1>`.

Try:

```css
.site-link, .site-logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Oh my... this worked as a charm. Thank you so much!!!